# How to optimize the sorting of a vector with coordinates based on distance?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I need to sort a vector of coordinates (x, y >= 1) in a way that every next point from the vector is the closest one to the previous by calculating the distance with the formula from getDistance().

My current solution is too slow as I need the program to be able to finish in 5 seconds or less with vector length (N) equal to 100 000.

```
struct Point {
    int ind;
    int x;
    int y;
    double dist;
};



double getDist(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  return sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
}



vector<Point> cordSort(vector<Point> vect) {
    
    vector<Point> finalDistVect;
    finalDistVect.push_back(vect[0]);
    Point firstPoint = vect[0];
    vect.erase(vect.begin());

    for (i = 0; i < pcVect.size() - 1; i++) {

        sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [firstPoint](const Point & a, const Point & b) {
            return getDist(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y, a.x, a.y) < getDist(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y, b.x, b.y);
        });

        finalDistVect.push_back(vect[0]);
        finalDistVect[i].dist = getDist(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y, vect[0].x, vect[0].y);
        firstPoint = vect[0];
        vect.erase(vect.begin());
    }

    return finalDistVect;
}
```

vect is the initial vector with coordinates sorted by:

```
    sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](const Point & a, const Point & b) {
        if (a.x + a.y != b.x + b.y) {
            return a.x + a.y < b.x + b.y;
        }
        return a.x < b.x;
    });
```

I am thinking about implementing bucket sort but I don't know if it will work for my problem.

Comment: I don't think it'll be making it a lot faster but at least some: Skip `sqrt` and compare the squared distances instead. You'll get the same result.

Comment: I need to find the closest point to every point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using the wrong algorithm for this. Find a list of standard graph algorithms and see if you can identify something that might apply. This seems like HW/puzzle, so I'm not sure I should state directly.

Comment: @George Thanks for the feedback. Could you please show me a way to implement it.

Comment: You will necessarily have pairs (or triplets) of points that are the closest ones to each other. What do you do then? Similarly, you will have points that are too far from the others and aren't the closest to any other points (though there will be a closest point to them). How do you "sort" those?

Comment: @kabaAli That surely isn't the whole question? What determines the starting point of each person? How does a person visit points, and how many does each person visit? Is `K` just some number less than `N`? Please edit your question to include all the details. Your example gives `N = 5` yet I see only 4 points... how does that work?

Comment: @kabaAli `vector<Point>` --> `std::deque<Point>`.  Then `vect.erase(vect.begin());` --> `vect.pop_front();`.  Any improvements if you made those changes?

Comment: @kabaAli -- Those were my suggestions.  If they work, maybe it would be better for you to post an answer, and the reasons why it sped up the code.  Obviously the only change was to use a deque, and to use `pop_front`, so that is a clue as to the difference.

Comment: You can use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (no. 3) with a custom comparator lambda, function or function object that calculates the distance information

Comment: @oraqlle I was thinking about the same thing but I have no idea how to do it. Could you write the code for the sort and send it?

Comment: @kabaAli I have a [solution](https://www.godbolt.org/z/vGEnKcr14) that finds the closest points and then sorts based on that. It completes in ~23s with the `-O3` flag, however, because I've used the standard library, you can utilize the [`std::execution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) which drops it down to ~5.43069s. The godbolt link won't have the parallel version as godbolt can't support it and can only handle up to 10,000 points due to godbolts timeout, but I can post as an answer the parallel code.

Answer (score 0):

your implementation indeed increase inefficiency by repeatedly erase the first element from a `vector`. `std::vector` is not designed to be used to frequently erase elements from other the back.

Not sure if I read your algorithm correctly. The first element is predetermined as the first element of the input, then your program repeatedly find the points that has shortest distance from the last element (point) in the output point vector.

If that's the case, it has no benefit to `sort` at all.

A naive algorithm is like bubbling:

```
1. add first point to outputVector, add all rest to openSet;
2. if openSet is empty, we are done.
3. take the last point from output Vector, check with all points in `openSet`, to find the one with shortest distance from it, add it to outputVector, remove it from openSet;
4. goto 2
```

Basically I am recommending you do use a std::set to keep track of `openset`, or maybe even better, `std::unordered_set`.

Another way is to do it in place, just swap the chosen points with the one who is taking its place.

e.g. we have P0, P1, P2, P3, P4 as input in a `vector`

```
1. int pos = 1; // P0 is in right place, we are looking for 
                // the point that shall go to index 1;
2. check all points from index `pos` to `4`(which is the max index) and find the one with shortest distance from `P0`, let's say we get `P4`;
3. swap `P0` (the one at index `pos`) and `P4` (the chosen one);
4. ++ pos;
5. if pos!=4(max index), goto 2.
```

We are using `pos` to keep track of `sorted` and `open` and do it in place.

Comment: And by the way,  `vector<Point> cordSort(vector<Point> vect)`, the parameter should be passed in as a `const reference`, i.e., `vector<Point>& vect`. If you have no reason to keep the input vector intact, just pass in as `vector<Point>& vect` and operate directly on it.

Comment: This solution is almost the same as mine. The time complexity will not change much if it even does.

Comment: There is inert complexity of this problem. My algorithm is like `O(N^2)`, yours probably `O(N^2logN)` as you `sort`ed in each loop. Have you bothered to do the in-placed one and time the difference? There won't be magic, but I expect noticeable improvements.

Comment: if you are expect an `O(n log n)` algorithm, I would be glad to see one too. Building the `distance matrix` itself is a `O(n^2)` job, which is not necessary of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a sorting problem, you have to come up with a different algorithm. For example, there may be no solution at all, which would not be the case for a sorting problem.

Consider four points on a single line: `A=(1, 1), B=(100, 1), C=(101, 1), D=(1000, 1)`. Point `D` is not the closest point for any other point, so it should come first. Then we should put `C`, followed by `B`, and now we cannot put `A` because the closest point to `B` is actually `C`, not `A`.

And even if it was, you should come up with a faster algorithm. You have `N` iterations of the `for` loop, each iteration looks for the smallest element among `N` other elements, which is already at least `O(N^2)`. Using `sort` instead of `min_element` makes it even worse: `O(N^2 log N)`. This won't fly for `N ~ 100'000` at all in competitive programming/home assignments.